# Core Animation in Instruments file can't open and No Data

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6, xcode-instruments

I hope someone enlightens me with this:

After saving a trace file (example: filename.trace) and send it via email, how come the recipient couldn't open the file?
So, I decided to compress the trace file (example: filename.trace.zip) and send it again via email, the recipient was finally able to open the file, but he can only see the Trace template I used, NO DATA FOUND (no spiky stuff). (Same thing happens with putting the trace file in dropbox and send the link.)

Btw, I'm using Core Animation Trace Template (that might have something to do with it).

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions (I have no experience with this particular file):

- did you properly close the file? its possible what you are sending is a file that is not itself complete
- in the past, I set some flag in the app plist that let me share files with iTunes. You could try to copy the file to the shared location (Documents folder? not sure now) at the same time you email the file (and maybe email the new file not the original), and see if the one you grab from iTunes opens, and is different from the one that gets emailed

In the end, you need to determine if what you have on the file system is byte for byte what ends up getting received in email, and if the copied file from iTunes opens. Once you find this out, if the problem is not obvious, then update your question. Good luck.